# Get all changed files in a changest

Tags: regex, mercurial

I want to get all the changed file in a changeset but without having the letter that specify the change type.

I know this command

```
hg status --change changeset
```

However, this return result like,

```
A /path/to/file
M /path/to/file
```

I want the result to be

```
/path/to/file
```

without "A" or "M". I tried to do it with regular expression and it used to work but I don't know it didn't work in one scenario.

The regular expression,

```
/(?<=[MA]\s).+/
```

This the scenario that did not work

```
arwa/Documents/Projects/firefox/M db << notice M here.
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `^` (start of line) to your regex:

```
/(?<=^[MA]\s).+/
```

If you don't do that, `(?<=[MA]\s)` will lookabehind the `M` part and `.+` will catch `db`.

Answer (score 1):

As of Mercurial 3.5, you can use templates (still an experimental feature, you can see it with `hg help status -v`). Namely:

```
hg status --change <rev> --template '{path}\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use log with template?

```
hg log -r CSET -T "{files % '{file}\n'}"
```

will produce clean output

```
lang/UTF-8/serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php
plugins/serendipity_event_bbcode/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php
plugins/serendipity_event_emoticate/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php
plugins/serendipity_event_karma/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php
plugins/serendipity_event_s9ymarkup/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php
plugins/serendipity_plugin_shoutbox/UTF-8/lang_ru.inc.php
```

contrary to templated status

```
'lang\UTF-8\serendipity_lang_ru.inc.php
''plugins\serendipity_event_bbcode\UTF-8\lang_ru.inc.php
''plugins\serendipity_event_emoticate\UTF-8\lang_ru.inc.php
''plugins\serendipity_event_karma\UTF-8\lang_ru.inc.php
''plugins\serendipity_event_s9ymarkup\UTF-8\lang_ru.inc.php
''plugins\serendipity_plugin_shoutbox\UTF-8\lang_ru.inc.php
'
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution